# Feeding baby animals

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Lately I have noticed that you can now feed baby animals. When you feed them, you get the same animation as when you use bonemeal on a plant (little green stars).

But so far, that's it. I fed a baby chicken an entire stack of seeds, and I'm sitting here, staring at the same baby chick.

Am I doing it wrong? Am I meant to feed them other things? Or is the RNG just not on my side?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the Wiki, feeding the "Breeding Item" for that animal takes of 10% of the remianing time for them to grow up

> Baby animals grow into full sized animals after twenty minutes (one game day, beds notwithstanding). Their growth can now slowly be accelerated using the animal's breeding item, where each use takes 10% off the remaining time to grow up.

[Source](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Baby_animals#Baby_animals)

What would be happening if that each time you have fed the animal the remaining time for them has been reduces by 10%, but since it's affecting the remaining time the amount it's being reduced by is getting smaller each time.

```
100 - (100 / 10) = 90           - 10 was taken away
90 - (90 / 10) = 81             - 9 was taken away
81 - (81 / 10) = 72.9           - 8.1 was taken away
72.9 - (72.9 / 10) = 65.61      - 7.29 was taken away
65.61 - (65.61 / 10) = 59.049   - 6.561 was taken away
```

get the picture? mind you i just started with 100 cause it's easier, the 20 minutes would actually be worked out as 24000 ticks in Minecraft (so replace the 100 i used)

you probably just need to wait a little while, since the original time is one full day you wont have to be up so long

> after twenty minutes (one game day, beds notwithstanding)

Comment: lucky Minecraft makes it easy to work out the 10% apart since to 10% is 1/10th of the value which is just value / 10

Answer (score -5):

When I play. The baby animal I'm feeding gradually gets bigger but quicker than it normally would. The trick is don't feed it too much or it'll grow even slower.

Comment: There is no such thing as overfeeding baby animals to increase the time it takes to grow.

Comment: This is incorrect and misleading.